# Bake wings frozen or thawed?

Tags: oven, thawing, chicken-wings

I've never baked wings before in an oven and would like to try out [this recipe](http://www.marthastewart.com/326508/emerils-oven-roasted-chicken-wings), however it doesn't state whether you start with frozen or thawed wings, nor does it speak to their internal temperature so that I know when they're done. I bought some wings from the store and the bag says to bake them frozen for 50 mins, whereas this recipe calls for a total of 30 mins.

So I ask: when baking wings, do you start with them frozen or thawed, and what is the proper temperature for them to be at the very end?

Comment: FWIW I was able to dig and find [this article](http://eggheadforum.com/discussion/1153260/frozen-or-thawed-chicken-wings) where the consensus is that although you *can* bake wings frozen, you *should* really let them thaw first. But no one really qualifies their opinions with anything science-y. Wondering if there's a heightened risk for bacteria/food poisoning, or maybe cooking frozen kills some of the flavor...